# Attaching a txt-file in mailcomposer ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

When use my following script, then the picture and the logfile would be a attached file. Also some other Text (the default signature) from the email would be attached as index.htm to the email when i open it with Outlook.

The Email is sent out from the iPad with iOS 7.0.6

In the Mail-Application on the Mac, the Files are in the middle of the text, before the signature of the mail-application would be written.

When i attach only the image, then all would be fine. When i attache also the logfile.txt, then its like I have descripted and in the Mail-Application of the mac, all special keys (german like ä, ü) are not decoded as utf8.

Where did I make the mistake?

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

currentIOS = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

vNumber = @"V"VersionNumber;

subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Meine aktuelle iPad-Nummer",vNumber];

message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>Hallo liebes EDV-Team,</p> <p>mein Betriebssystem ist: %@</p><p>Und meine iPad-Nummer lautet: %@</p>", currentIOS, udid];

[controller setToRecipients: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@webpage.de", nil]];
[controller setSubject:subject];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *txtFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logfile.txt"];
NSData *noteData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath];

[controller addAttachmentData:noteData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"logfile.txt"];

UIImage *roboPic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"world_smilie.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(roboPic);
[controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"smile.png"];

[controller setMessageBody:message isHTML:YES];

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I changed the code for the textfile:

```
I change the code like elio.d told me:

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *txtFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logfile.txt"];
NSString *txtFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSData *txtFileData = [txtFileContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[controller addAttachmentData:txtFileData
                     mimeType:@"text/plain"
                     fileName:@"logfile.txt"];
```

The logfile.txt would be attached but the signature from the ipad would be attached to the email in ATT00002.htm and now i got also a empty ATT00001.htm

I have the same problem when i change the type of the email (isHTML:NO)

Comment: Try updating your `message` text to include the `<html>` and `<body>` tags so it is valid HTML.

Comment: FYI - why do you check for the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method? Are you supporting iOS 4.3? If not, there is no need for the check.

Comment: @rmaddy: i have added the tags, but when i add the text-file then the signatur of my mail would be attached as ATT00001.htm. I change "isHTML" to NO

Comment: Regarding the encoding try to load the content of the file in an NSString using the right encoding and right after initialize the NSData using the string and the right encoding